# Use selective features out of a JavaRDD with many features

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, feature-extraction

I am using Spark Mllib with Hadoop in one of the big data analytics applications.
I have a feature set of 41 features and one label. Now, while training, I want to mix and match my features to feature engineer and find the best suited minimal set of features for my scenario.

For this I want to select at training time which features to use while training and testing for model accuracy.

I am doing this

```
JavaRDD<LabeledPoint>[] splits = data.randomSplit(new double[] { 0.5, 0.5 });
JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> trainingData = splits[0];
JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> testData = splits[1];
```

and later training different models using that data.

```
modelLR = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS().setNumClasses(numClasses).run(trainingData.rdd());
modelRF = RandomForest.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses, categoricalFeaturesInfo, numTrees, featureSubsetStrategy, impurity, maxDepth, maxBins, seed);
modelNB = NaiveBayes.train(trainingData.rdd(), 1.0);
modelGBT = GradientBoostedTrees.train(trainingData, boostingStrategy);
modelDT = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses, categoricalFeaturesInfo, impurity, maxDepth, maxBins);
```

Now, before training the models with dataset, I want filter the data for selective features that I want to use. Can someone suggest me a way to do this out of `JavaRDD<LabeledPoint>`?

If any more details needed, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I figured the answer on my own.

For anyone interested in doing this I did something like this.

```
public static JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> filterData(JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> data, String filterString) {
        return data.map(new Function<LabeledPoint, LabeledPoint>() {
            @Override
            public LabeledPoint call(LabeledPoint point) throws Exception {
                double label = point.label();
                double[] features = point.features().toArray();
                String[] featuresInUse = filterString.split(",");
                double[] filteredFeatures = new double[featuresInUse.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < featuresInUse.length; i++) {
                    filteredFeatures[i] = features[Integer.parseInt(VectorizationProperties.getProperty(featuresInUse[i]))];
                }
                LabeledPoint newPoint = new LabeledPoint(label, Vectors.dense(filteredFeatures));
                System.out.println(newPoint);
                return newPoint;
            }
        });
    }
```

Which will filter each record and give back the filtered JavaRDD.

Please  feel free to ask for any details needed to understand further.